# Error when inserting to EventException table using the id of the table Events

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a table Events(id) and table EventException(event_id, from_new_date, to_new_date) having event_id is the foreign key of the Events table.

I dont know what happen to this one, when i run i got error in =>.

```
$events = Events::find($id);
$exception = EventException::create(request()->all(), 'event_id' => $events);
return $exception;
```

I dont know when i want to get id from table Events and create new item in EventException do i write this correct or not.

Thank you.

--updated--
I got the error when my input in raw data is

```
{
    "from_new_date" :  "2018-10-13 09:00:00",
    "to_new_date" : "2018-10-13 16:00:00",
    "event_id" : 3
}
```

and i got the error like this:

```
"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`capstone_project`.`event_exceptions`, CONSTRAINT `event_exceptions_event_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `events` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `event_exceptions` (`from_new_date`, `to_new_date`, `event_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2018-10-13 09:00:00, 2018-10-13 16:00:00, {\"id\":3,\"event_title\":\"Project HR Calendar\",\"event_type_id\":3,\"from_date\":\"2018-10-10 10:00:00\",\"to_date\":null,\"is_recurring\":0,\"created_by\":\"HR Manager\",\"remarks\":null,\"created_at\":\"2018-10-21 02:35:12\",\"updated_at\":\"2018-10-21 02:35:12\"}, 2018-10-21 13:20:53, 2018-10-21 13:20:53))"
```

How can i create with only save the event_id and dont get any other. Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone help me with the Integrity constraint violation ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sure have some unconventional way of naming a model `Exception`. LOL

I assume your `request()->all()` looks like:

```
['event_id'      => ...,
 'from_new_date' => ..., 
 'to_new_date'   => ...]
```

Try this:

```
$event = Event::find(request()->input('event_id'));
$eventException = EventException::make(request()->all());
$eventException->event()->associate($event);
$eventException->save();
return $eventException;
```

Comment: i will try this. I am not sure if i can find the id and then create the new exception or not. I will try

Comment: Got the undefined variable ($id)

Comment: Well, I assumed you **have** `$id` defined. I can't help you without it.

Comment: What's in your `$request->all()`?

Comment: no no i mean the code that you give me for sample, it contains undefined variable id. I set the name of that function is public function storeException(EventExceptionRequest $exception_request)

Comment: The event_id cannot be null, but the problem is i write the event_id is correct but it still said id cant be null.

Comment: Yes, because a `FOREIGN KEY` prevents it. Your `Event` model has to exist before you can create an `EventException` model.

Comment: This is in my Model: Events

public function event_exception() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\EventException
            ', 'event_id', 'id');
    }

and in EventException
public function event(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Events
            ','event_id', 'id');
    } 

I dont know do i write is correct or not

Comment: And the Events table already have item so that i can create a new EventException